# Suppress ticks in plot in r

Tags: r, plot, axis, axis-labels

I want to remove labels and axis from X axis, however adding new ticks.

```
plot(1:10, ylab = "")
at1 <- seq(1, 10, 0.1)
axis(side = 1, at = at1, labels = FALSE)
```

I could not get rid of y labels.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

see `?par`  You need the `xaxt` argument

```
plot(1:10, ylab = "", xaxt='n')
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are using double quotes in `""` and single quotes in `'n'`?

Comment: @Nisba personally I use `''` with a character and `""` with a string.

Comment: This is not only suppressing the ticks, but also the labels. Example:

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
axis(1, xaxt='n', labels=0:1, at=0:1)

Answer (score 4):

I am not certain what you want, but this removes the x label and uses the tick marks you are generating with at1:

```
plot(1:10, ylab = "", xlab="")
at1 <- seq(1, 10, 0.1)
axis(side =1, at1, labels = F)
```

I took the suggestion by GSee to remove the y tick marks if you also want to do that.

```
plot(1:10, xlab = "", ylab = "", yaxt='n')
at1 <- seq(1, 10, 0.1)
axis(side =1, at1, labels = F)
```