# Create a histogram for weighted values

Tags: r, plot, histogram, weighted-graph

If I have a vector (e.g., `v<-runif(1000)`), I can plot its histogram (which will look, more or less, as a horizontal line because `v` is a sample from the uniform distribution).

However, suppose I have a vector and its associated weights (e.g., `w<-seq(1,1000)` in addition to `v<-sort(runif(1000))`). E.g., this is the result of `table()` on a much larger data set.

How do I plot the new histogram? (it should look more of less like the `y=x` line in this example).

I guess I could reverse the effects of `table` by using `rep` (`hist(rep(v,w))`) but this "solution" seems ugly and resource-heavy (creates an intermediate vector of size `sum(w)`), and it only supports integer weights.

Comment: You can add `weight` to the aesthetic mapping in `ggplot` then use `geom_histogram`

Comment: @JakeBurkhead I didn't know that! Could you please add that as an answer?

Comment: You can also `plot` the `table`. The result isn't quite a histogram, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Package `plotrix`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html) has a function `weighted.hist` which does what you want:

```R
w<-seq(1,1000)
v<-sort(runif(1000))
weighted.hist(v, w)
```

[image: Example of <code>weighted.hist</code>]

Comment: Just fyi, the link is dead. Here is info about the package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html

Comment: @Adam_G Thanks! Updated the link in the answer.

Comment: The function is bugged: when I try to add a curve to it, it does not plot it at the right place... Try for instance ` weighted.hist(rnorm(T),rep(1,T)/T,col="wheat");curve(dnorm(x),add=TRUE)`

Comment: Why do the lines go below the x axis? or rather how can you stop the lines going below the x axis?

Comment: @DavidPell Those are ticks on the x-axis. This may help in getting rid of those: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393076/suppress-ticks-in-plot-in-r

Comment: @musically_ut ok fair enough - just a question of style. I was able to remove them with: `weighted.hist(v,w, xaxis=FALSE)`

Answer (score 35):

```
library(ggplot2)
w <- seq(1,1000)
v <- sort(runif(1000))

foo <- data.frame(v, w)

ggplot(foo, aes(v, weight = w)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic; so easy to do weighted histograms - and it works! But "weight" is not listed in the documentation (ggplot 3.1.1) as an aesthetic for geom_histogram(...). How did you know about it?

Comment: It's used in the examples for [`geom_histogram`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html#examples). Not sure how I knew about it 5+ years ago

Answer (score 6):

An alternative from the `weights` package is `wtd.hist()`

`w<-seq(1,1000)
v<-sort(runif(1000))
wtd.hist(x=v,weight=w)`

[image]