# Histogram with weights in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I need to plot a weighted histogram of density rather than frequency. I know that `freq = FALSE` is available in `hist()` but you can't specify weights. In `ggplot2` I can do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
w <- seq(1,1000)
w <-w/sum(w)
v <- sort(runif(1000))

foo <- data.frame(v, w)

ggplot(foo, aes(v, weight = w)) + geom_histogram()
```

But where is the equivalent of `freq = FALSE`?

Comment: @ALexA. ho would I then set fre=F and not to null which is the default in hist()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a histogram for weighted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841204/create-a-histogram-for-weighted-values)

Answer (score 14):

By default, `geom_histogram()` will use frequency rather than density on the y-axis. However, you can change this by setting your `y` aesthetic to `..density..` like so:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x = v, y = ..density.., weight = w)) + geom_histogram()
```

This will produce a weighted histogram of `v` with density on the y-axis.

[image: weighted_density_histogram]

You can also do this with the `freq` argument in `weighted.hist()` from the `plotrix` package:

```
library(plotrix)
with(foo, weighted.hist(v, w, freq = FALSE))
```

[image: plotrix]