# R: relative frequency categorical data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency, categorical-data

I'm working in **Rstudio**.

With ggplot2, I'm trying to form a plot where I have frequencies of a categorical variable (number of shares purchased), per category (there are 5 categories). *For example, members of category A might buy 1 share more frequently than members of category D.*

I now have a count plot. However, because one category is much bigger than the others, you don't get a good idea about the n shares in the other categories.

The code of the count plot is as follows:

```
#ABS. DISTRIBUTION SHARES/CATEGORY
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Number_share, fill=category)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, alpha=.5, position="dodge")
```

This results in this graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRyx6.jpg

Therefore, I am planning to make a plot where, instead of an absolute count, you have a distribution relative to their category.

I calculated the **relative frequencies** of each category:

```
library(MASS)
categories = dat$category
categories.freq = table(categories)
categories.relfreq = categories.freq / nrow(dat)
cbind(categories.relfreq)
```

> categories.relfreq
>
> Beauvent 1        0.002708692
>
> Beauvent 2        0.015020931
>
> E&B               0.037182960
>
> Ecopower 1        0.042107855
>
> Ecopower 2        0.029549372
>
> Ecopower 3        0.873183945

I don't know how to make a plot where the frequency of a share number acquisition is **relative to the category**, instead of absolute. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Number_share, fill=category)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill")
```

This will stack the categories on top of each other and the `position="fill"` argument will give the relative counts

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want each n_share category to add up to 100%. Instead, I'd like the total of shares acquired by each member category to add up to 100%. 

Your answer leads to: https://ibb.co/dcgxTS

Instead I'm looking for a relative version of this absolute graph: https://imgur.com/a/e4k94

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem is very similar: [Histogram with weights in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355938/histogram-with-weights-in-r)
basically it's because the default of a histogram is to use counts on the y-axis, while I want to use a hist(freq=TRUE), or in the case of ggplot:  ggplot_histogram(y= ..density..).