# Geom_freqpoly with Predefined Count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can plot `geom_freqpoly` without problems using the number of observation

```
ggplot(data=demo) +
 geom_freqpoly(mapping=aes(x = value))
```

[image]

But I'd like to use the *precalculated obeservation count contained in the data*.

I tried using `stat = "identity"` but it apparently doesn't work.

```
ggplot(data=demo) +
 geom_freqpoly(mapping=aes(x = value, y = cnt), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

This is my sample data

```
demo  <- tribble(
 ~value,    ~cnt,
 .25, 20,
 .25, 30,
 .1, 40
)
```

Comment: This is the problem I stumble back into, waiting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the similar problem for [histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843767/4808122) the solution seems to be as simple as to use the `weight` parameter in the aesthetics.

The solution using the sample data from the other answer would be

```
demo <- data.frame(value = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75, 0.1),
                   cnt = c(5, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7) * 10e8,
                   group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 3))


ggplot(demo, aes(value, weight = cnt, color = group)) + geom_freqpoly()
```

[image]

Comment: @dd_rookie is this the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: You didn't get the graph you want, because the data of pre-calculated counts you passed to ggplot was **NOTHING** like what was used to produce the freqpoly graph.

Since you didn't include code for the original `demo` used to generate graph 1, I'll venture a guess:

```
demo.orig <- data.frame(value = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.1))

p <- ggplot(demo.orig, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_freqpoly()
p # show plot to verify its appearance, which matches the graph in the question
layer_data(p) # look at the calculated data used by geom_freqpoly

`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
   y count          x       xmin       xmax       width   density ncount ndensity PANEL group colour size linetype alpha
1  0     0 0.09310345 0.09051724 0.09568966 0.005172414   0.00000    0.0      0.0     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
2  1     1 0.09827586 0.09568966 0.10086207 0.005172414  64.44444    0.5      0.5     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
3  0     0 0.10344828 0.10086207 0.10603448 0.005172414   0.00000    0.0      0.0     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
... (omitted to conserve space)
30 0     0 0.24310345 0.24051724 0.24568966 0.005172414   0.00000    0.0      0.0     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
31 2     2 0.24827586 0.24568966 0.25086207 0.005172414 128.88889    1.0      1.0     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
32 0     0 0.25344828 0.25086207 0.25603448 0.005172414   0.00000    0.0      0.0     1    -1  black  0.5        1    NA
```

From a small dataframe with only two unique values, `stat_bin` generated a much larger dataframe with the x-axis split into 30 bins (the default number), and count / y = 0 everywhere except for the two bins containing the original values.

```
> geom_freqpoly
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "bin", position = "identity", 
    ..., na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) 
{
    params <- list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
    if (identical(stat, "bin")) {
        params$pad <- TRUE
    }
    layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPath, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = params)
}
```

A quick check by printing `geom_freqpoly` to console shows that its underlying geom is simply `GeomPath`, which plots x/y pairs in sequential order.

In other words, if you want to get the peaks from graph 1, you need to provide a similar dataset, with rows indicating where y should drop to 0. While it's certainly possible to calculate this by digging into the code for `StatBin$compute_group`, I'd think it's simpler to expand from the data of pre-calculated counts and let ggplot do its normal job:

```
demo %>%
  tidyr::uncount(cnt) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_freqpoly() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: plot]

---

**Edit**: solution without fully expanding dataframe of aggregated counts

Sample dataset with 2 groups:

```
demo <- data.frame(value = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.1, 0.25, 0.75, 0.1),
                   cnt = c(5, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7) * 10e8,
                   group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 3))
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

demo %>%
  rename(x = value, y = cnt) %>% # rename here so approach below can be easily applied
                                 # to other datasets with different column names
  tidyr::nest(data = c(x, y)) %>% # nest to apply same approach for each group

  mutate(data = purrr::map(
    data,
    function(d) ggplot2:::bin_vector( # cut x's range into appropriate bins
      x = d$x,
      bins = ggplot2:::bin_breaks_bins(
        x_range = range(d$x),
        bins = 30), # default bin count is 30; change if desired
      pad = TRUE) %>%
      select(x, xmin, xmax) %>%

      # place y counts into the corresponding x bins (this is probably similar
      # to interval join, but I don't have that package installed on my machine)
      tidyr::crossing(d %>% rename(x2 = x)) %>%
      mutate(y = ifelse(x2 >= xmin & x2 < xmax, y, 0)) %>%
      select(-x2) %>%
      group_by(x) %>%
      filter(y == max(y)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      unique())) %>%

  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(data)) %>% # unnest to get one flat dataframe back

  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) + # plot as per normal
  geom_path() +
  theme_bw()

# package versions used: dplyr 1.0.0, ggplot2 3.3.1, tidyr 1.1.0, purrr 0.3.4
```

[image: result]

Comment: This provides an expected result, but basically by transforming the aggregated data back to its single observation level (which I intended to avoid). Anyway this answer deserves an upvote not least because the mention of  `layer_data` (which I didn't know and had no idea how could I find it). Wouldn't you mind to provide some information on the `compute_group`, so I can accept the answer? Please re run the sample data with a count of `40M` instead of `40` to see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I somehow didn't receive the notice about the update. *Many thanks for the detailed explanation* with the sample code. I think the mention of `ggplot2:::bin_vector` is crucial because of the parameter `weight`; which led me to the solution. Wouldn't you mind you to review my alternative answer, so I can accept it if it would be found complete.